# Post score not taking place but leaderboard UI shows

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am setting up a leaderboard service that i have implemented with the GooglePlayGames api. My authentication and showing the leaderboard works but my script for posting scores to the leaderboard does not work. I have been looking around for quite a while now and it seems like the syntax for posting score is always the same, which i have aswell.

```
    void Start()
{
    AuthenticateUser();
}

void AuthenticateUser()
{
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
    {
        if (success == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Logged in to Google play");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("There was an error login in to Google Play");
        }
    });
}

public static void PostToLeaderboard(long newScore)
{
    Social.ReportScore(10, GPGSIds.leaderboard_highscore, (bool success) =>
    {
        if (success == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Score were sucessfully added to leaderboard");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Unable to post score to leaderboard"); 
        }
    });
}
```

This is my code for authenticating and post score to the leaderboard. I have hard coded 10 in the code Social.ReportScore function call.

Any ideas on why this is? The leaderboardUI shows up but no scores.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to run the method `PostToLeaderboard(long newScore)` to update your leaderboard before you call `leaderboardUI`  method.

Here in this case you can try this.

```
puplic void leaderboardUI() {
    PostToLeaderboard(long newScore);
    // your code to show leaderboard
}
```